# arraylist of a three-dimensional integer vector

Tags: java

I have this three-dimensional array named bands. I need to do 4 copies of it, so I can work in parallel with all of them.

```
int bands[][][] = new int[param][][];
```

I need the array to keep being a three dimensional array, as it is the input for some methods that needs an `int [][][]`

How could I do such copies? I was thinking about using an arrayList like this:

```
List<Integer[][][]> bandsList = new ArrayList<Integer[][][]>();

bandsList.add(bands);
```

but I get this error on the last line: The method `add(Integer[][][])` in the type `List<Integer[][][]>` is not applicable for the arguments `(int[][][])`

so what should I do??

Comment: Use `List<int[][][]>` instead. But what you are doing is making me crazy. Why you actually want to do something like this? Is there any specific use case which forces you?

Comment: Storing an array in a list won't make any copy of the array. You'll just have 4 references to the same array.

Comment: O.o. Seems like I missed the major issue there.

Comment: Not the best idea to copy something in order to access it concurrently..its difficult to modify all the copy and merge them.

Comment: first... I didn't know List<Integer[][][]> was different from List<int[][][]>, so thanks... you can assume I am pretty lost

So I had in mind that if I had such list I could then use:

for (int i=0; i<4;i++){ method(Listbands.get(i)) }

Comment: so... I don't want 4 references to the same array, I actually need 4 different copies and then store them in the arrayList... what is the best way to do such copies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors is because `int[][][]` is not the same as `Integer[][][]`.

`int[][][]` is an **3D array of primitive** `int`.

`Integer[][][]` is an **3D array of object** `Integer`, which is the wrapper class of `int`.

Well, technically a 3D array is an array of pointers to a 2D array, which is an array of pointers to a 1D array which is an array of primitives or pointers to objects.

Use `List<int[][][]> bandsList = new ArrayList<int[][][]>();` instead.

Also note that

```
bandsList.add(bands);
bandsList.add(bands);
```

will simply add 2 **pointers** to the same array, changing one will also change the other.

You'll need to manually copy them:

```
int[][][] getCopy(int[][][] bands)
{
  int[][][] newBands = new int[bands.length][][];
  for (int i = 0; i < bands.length; i++)
  {
    newBands[i] = new int[bands[i].length];
    for (int j = 0; j < bands[i].length; j++)
    {
      newBands[i][j] = new int[bands[i][j].length];
      System.arraycopy(bands, 0, newBands, 0, bands[i][j].length))
    }
  }
  return newBands;
}

// to add
bandsList.add(getCopy(bands));
```

Answer (score 0):

in this way you aren't doing a copy of the array, you have to do this 4 times:

```
    int cloneList[][][] = new int[param][..][..];
    for(int i = 0; i<bands.length; i++) {
       int arr1[][] = bands[i];
       for(int j = 0; j<arr1.length; j++) {
           int arr2[] = arr1[j];
           for(int k = 0; k<arr2.length; k++) {
               int x = arr2[k];
               cloneList[i][j][k] = x;
           }
       }
    }
```